# How superimpose view in WatchKit

Tags: ios, iphone, view, interface, watchkit

Can you explain me how the Lovoo App do this ?

[image: Lovoo]

[image]

The heart in the center is above the others button or I don't understand how we can press any button without changing the color of the heart to  hightlighted...

Thx in advance

Comment: This is most-likely done using 5 background images (1 for each selected state and 1 for none selected) . The 4 buttons are place in a master group, the master group has the background image(s) and the 4 buttons have no background (transparent). They then change the background image of the master group when the user selects a button.